# The input value is not sent to the firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angular-material2

I have an angular material form.

add-beer.component.html

```
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" name="mSladu" matInput placeholder="Hmotnosť sladu" #beerMSLadu="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="beer.mSladu">          
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" name="hRmutu" matInput placeholder="Hustota rmutu" #beerHRmutu="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="beer.hRmutu">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" name="predOHlNalevu" matInput placeholder="Predpokladaný objem hl. nálevu" #beerPredOHlNalevu="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="beer.predOHlNalevu" [value]="beer.hRmutu * beer.mSladu">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" name="predOPredku" matInput placeholder="Predpokladaný objem predku" #beerPredOPredku="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="beer.predOHlNalevu * 1.3">
        </mat-form-field>
```

*add-beer.component.ts* function, which is fired on submit form

```
onSubmit({value, valid}: { value: Beer, valid: boolean }) {
    if (!valid) {
        // Show error
        this.flashMessage.show('Prosím zadajte povinné údaje', {
            cssClass: 'alert-warn', timeauto: 4000
        });
    } else {
        // Add new client
        this.beerService.newBeer(value);
        // Show message
        this.flashMessage.show('Údaje boli uspešne uložené', {
            cssClass: 'alert-success', timeauto: 4000
        });
        // Redirect to dashboars
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
}
```

*beer.service.ts*

```
newBeer(beer: Beer) {
this.beersCollection.add(beer);
```

}

**Question 1**

Input with name **mSladu** and **hRmutu** mSladu and hRmut are multiplied and the result is entered as the Value of input, but I send the form but when the form is sent, only the mSladu and hRmutu values are saved in Firebase.

**Question 2**

When I want multiply value of **predOHlNalevu** and show as value of **predOPredku** so nothing happend and input stay empty.

Thanks for help

**Edit:**
in add-beer.component.ts I have defined an object

```
beer: Beer = {
    mSladu: null,
    hRmutu: null,
    predOHlNalevu: null,
    predOPredku: null
};
```

Beer[] get from model Beer.ts

Comment: Any error occur? Show something in console?

Comment: For multiply try format: {{(someValue * otherValue)}}

Comment: Why you not build object value: beer inside your methord 'onSubmit' ?

Comment: no error showed in console and terminal. I try both format with and without brackets. Multiply work because the results show in inoput value but it will not be sent to firebase only value mSladu and hRmutu. What do you mean build object value? Thaks!!

Comment: onSubmit(){ beer: Beer = new Beer(); beer.mSladu = 'someValue'; beer.predOPredku = 'formValue;...'  this.beerService.newBeer(beer); } something like this.

Comment: why 'null' in properties? 

beer: Beer = {
    mSladu: : number;
    hRmutu: number;
    predOHlNalevu: number;
    predOPredku: number;
};

Comment: Not is better create a class?:     export class Beer{
    mSladu: : number;
    hRmutu: number; 
    predOHlNalevu: number; 
    predOPredku: number; 
    
    constructor() {}
    }

Comment: in file Beer.ts I have defined interface: export interface Beer{mSladu?: number; hRmutu?: number; predOHlNalevu?: number; predOPredku?: number;}. Sorry but I still learn angular so I have problem with some thinks. Would it help if I upload it to github and send it?

Comment: You <input class=""> not have a <formControlName="someName"> are this correct? https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control

Answer (score 0):

Beer.ts

```
export class Candidate {
    mSladu: number;
    hRmutu: number;
    predOHlNalevu: number;
    predOPredku: number;

    constructor() {}
}
```

...

```
onSubmit() {
    if (!valid) {
beer: Beer = new Beer()
beer.mSladu = 'getFormValue'; 
beer.hRmutu = 'getFormValue';
beer.predOHlNalevu = 'getFormValue';
beer.predOPredku = 'getFormValue';
...
this.beerService.newBeer(beer);
...
 }
}
```

If  you are using some type of **FormGroup** in your form, then you can change `'getFormValue'` above by this line below:

```
this.yourFormGrouName.get('mSladu').value,
```